# How did the humans make "Transformium" come to life?

Tags: transformers, transformers-age-of-extinction, transformers-live-action-series

I don't know if this was explained in *Transformers 4: Age of Extinction* or I missed it, but how did Joshua Joyce and his organisation make "Transformium" come to life?

From previous Michael Bay Transformer movies, all technology and transformers not alive (active?) required the allspark/Energon to give them life.

Basically what power source was making the Transformium come to life?

Comment: All of the transformers are powered by bad writing.

Comment: You mean, Transformers 4 contains a *plot hole?!*

Comment: All the transformer movies are, as Richard said, bad writing.  The first movie they get their life from the All-Spark.  The second and third, it's energon.  The fourth, it's transformium.  Honestly, Bay butchered his own series of movies by not sticking to his own cannon.

Answer (score 3):

Joshua is not actually giving power to the Transformium. He finds that Transformium can be manipulated by programing the Transformium matter.

We write computer programs which controls the electrical signals inside devices of a computer to make them do tasks we need. As such, we can program Transformium matter and make them do whatever we want; like to change the shape.

Any and every Transformer has a Spark. This contains all the memory of a Transformer (as Optimus Prime describes in Transformers 4 movie) and it is also the controlling power of the Transformium within a Transformers body. Spark of a Transformer can be thought as the soul/mind (whether it is the soul or the mind is another question to be asked and we do not need to follow on it here) of a human which controls and powers the body. We believe the soul goes away or mind disappears when a human dies. As such, a Ttansformer will not live without a Spark.

Without a Spark, Transformium is not controlled and they will be divided into parts and lay on the ground since there is no authority to bind them together and make a form of a Transformer. This thing can be seen very well in the seen where the Jetfire dies.

So in the nature, the Spark powers up a Transformer and controls the Transformium. What Joshua does is controlling the Transformium using computer programs. So computer program does the controlling part of the Spark. But it doesn't powers up the man made Transformer. I'm sorry but I couldn't find any reliable source which describes the power source of a man made Transformer.

AllSpark in the other hand is a power source which can create, repair or re-energize a spark.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly coming to life. Joshua is led to believe that he is the one controlling the transformers he created by using computers, by Megatron who is manipulating Joshua to build himself a new body.

There is no life source which is shown that gives life to those transformers built. So we can assume that it is just like an electrical appliance that uses electricity to function, since it is Joshua who is creating these transformers.

Answer (score 0):

Galvatron, the first Transformium-bodied transformer doesn't have a spark at all. It even tells Optimus Prime this fact when the latter stabs into the former's chest.I would believe that its powered by electricity since its essentially a robot, although the mechanics producing electricity inside it would be made up of Transformium itself so as to make those special transformations possible as any other explanation is not given in the movie.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Bay destroyed his own continuity. Joshua Joyce, the ceo of KSI, states that transformers are made of transformium. This is complete nonsense. If they're made of this substance how is Cade Yeager able to repair Optimus Prime? How is the Allspark able to create transformers out of ordinary machines as we see in the first movie? transformium is a rare earth metal. That means it's rare! None of the machines turned into miniature transformers in the first movie were made out of transformium. It's complete and utter nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

In *Transformers: Age of Extinction*, I believe it was implied that the creators used Transforium to build Cybertron and the cube has a super sophisticated programming tool which turned the Transforium into Cybertronians and organized it into a planet - Cybertron.